# phpmyadmin mysql gone away

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I got the "MySQL has gone away" error in phpMyAdmin when trying to display a single database. 
I have 9 databases in MySQL and the 8 of them works fine, but when I try to display the one database that I want to use it fails with "MySQL has gone away" error. I have tried to increase max_allowed_packet and wait_timeout but with no success.

If I display the site that uses this database there is no error.

I am on Ubuntu and running mysql as localhost.

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: I think I got it solved somehow by issuing some mysqladmin commands via terminal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it solved somehow by issuing some mysqladmin commands via terminal.